# Nextcloud: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php-fpm, freebsd, lighttpd, nextcloud

I'm installing Nextcloud on a FreeBSD system and I'm using `lighttpd` behind a `nginx` reverse proxy with terminal SSL.

`lighttpd` is able to serve static `html` files and can serve `index.php`, but without any styles, just the text.

When running `lighttpd -D -f /usr/local/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` and accessing `cloud2.myhostname.com` there's a bunch of errors as shown below.

The document root and all descendants are owned by `www:www`, the user and group under which `lighttpd` is running.
All directories have permission of `770`.  All files have permission of `660`.

The `lighttpd` error log shows that FastCGI is running, and the FastCGI is returning an error trace, which `lighttpd` logs as `FastCGI-stderr:` to indicate that the error trace is from it.

How to solve this?

```
server.c.1513) server started (lighttpd/1.4.59)
gw_backend.c.944) gw - found a host  0
gw_backend.c.944) gw - found a host  0
gw_backend.c.228) got proc: pid: 99023 socket: unix:/var/run/lighttpd/sockets/php.socket-2 load: 1
mod_fastcgi.c.487) FastCGI-stderr:{"reqId":"5HVsZcmvRCF7Qpm918A6","level":3,"time":"2021-10-25T22:03:55+00:00","remoteAddr":"111.222.33.44","user":"--","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"/index.php","message":"file_put_contents(/usr/local/www/nextcloud/data/.htaccess): Failed to open stream: Permission denied at /usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Setup.php#584","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; FreeBSD amd64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0","version":"","exception":{"Exception":"Error","Message":"file_put_contents(/usr/local/www/nextcloud/data/.htaccess): Failed to open stream: Permission denied at /usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Setup.php#584","Code":0,"Trace":[{"function":"onError","class":"OC\\Log\\ErrorHandler","type":"::"},{"file":"/usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Setup.php","line":584,"function":"file_put_contents"},{"file":"/usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Setup.php","line":222,"function":"protectDataDirectory","class":"OC\\Setup","type":"::"},{"file":"/usr/local/www/nextcloud/core/Controller/SetupController.php","line":57,"function":"getSystemInfo","class":"OC\\Setup","type":"->"},{"file":"/usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/base.php","line":939,"function":"run","class":"OC\\Core\\Controller\\SetupController","type":"->","args":["*** sensitive parameters replaced ***"]},{"file":"/usr/local/www/nextcloud/index.php","line":36,"function":"handleRequest","class":"OC","type":"::"}],"File":"/usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Log/ErrorHandler.php","Line":92,"CustomMessage":"--"}}

mod_fastcgi.c.487) FastCGI-stderr:{"reqId":"5HVsZcmvRCF7Qpm918A6","level":3,"time":"2021-10-25T22:03:55+00:00","remoteAddr":"111.222.33.44","user":"--","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"/index.php","message":"file_put_contents(/usr/local/www/nextcloud/data/index.html): Failed to open stream: Permission denied at /usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Setup.php#585","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; FreeBSD amd64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0","version":"","exception":{"Exception":"Error","Message":"file_put_contents(/usr/local/www/nextcloud/data/index.html): Failed to open stream: Permission denied at /usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Setup.php#585","Code":0,"Trace":[{"function":"onError","class":"OC\\Log\\ErrorHandler","type":"::"},{"file":"/usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Setup.php","line":585,"function":"file_put_contents"},{"file":"/usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Setup.php","line":222,"function":"protectDataDirectory","class":"OC\\Setup","type":"::"},{"file":"/usr/local/www/nextcloud/core/Controller/SetupController.php","line":57,"function":"getSystemInfo","class":"OC\\Setup","type":"->"},{"file":"/usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/base.php","line":939,"function":"run","class":"OC\\Core\\Controller\\SetupController","type":"->","args":["*** sensitive parameters replaced ***"]},{"file":"/usr/local/www/nextcloud/index.php","line":36,"function":"handleRequest","class":"OC","type":"::"}],"File":"/usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Log/ErrorHandler.php","Line":92,"CustomMessage":"--"}}

mod_fastcgi.c.487) FastCGI-stderr:{"reqId":"5HVsZcmvRCF7Qpm918A6","level":2,"time":"2021-10-25T22:03:55+00:00","remoteAddr":"111.222.33.44","user":"--","app":"no app in context","method":"GET","url":"/index.php","message":"Could not detect any host in https:///data/htaccesstest.txt","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; FreeBSD amd64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0","version":""}

mod_fastcgi.c.487) FastCGI-stderr:{"reqId":"5HVsZcmvRCF7Qpm918A6","level":2,"time":"2021-10-25T22:03:55+00:00","remoteAddr":"111.222.33.44","user":"--","app":"no app in context","method":"GET","url":"/index.php","message":"Could not detect any host in http:///data/htaccesstest.txt","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; FreeBSD amd64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0","version":""}

mod_fastcgi.c.487) FastCGI-stderr:{"reqId":"5HVsZcmvRCF7Qpm918A6","level":3,"time":"2021-10-25T22:03:55+00:00","remoteAddr":"111.222.33.44","user":"--","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"/index.php","message":"fopen(/var/log/nextcloud/nextcloud.log): Failed to open stream: Permission denied at /usr/local/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Log/File.php#84","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; FreeBSD amd64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0","version":""}

gw_backend.c.303) released proc: pid: 99023 socket: unix:/var/run/lighttpd/sockets/php.socket-2 load: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in the `modules.conf` of `lighttpd`, I forgot to include the file `conf.d/fastcgi.conf`.
Just uncommented the line.